# proeblem deploying telport ha in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, teleport

I need to deploy teleport in kubernetes with ha, but it only raises a proxy pod

I tried this configuration but it only raises more than one auth pod for me

clusterName: test.internal.com
proxyListenerMode: multiplex

validateConfigOnDeploy: false

persistence:
enabled: true
existingClaimName: ""
volumeSize: 10Gi

highAvailability:
replicaCount: 2

```
podDisruptionBudget:
  enabled: true
  minAvailable: 1
```

sessionRecording: "node"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.